# is karma really works in islam?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis

is karma really works in our life? my background is hindu, i like to get to know all the religion. normally hindu people believes "karma". i am also really scared for "karma". Do you believes "karma" and how will it effect to our life?

Thank you.

Comment: Please define karma.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. "karma" is not an Islamic term define it first.

Comment: https://understandquran.com/quran-tell-us-karma-cc/

Answer (score 1):

### Equivalent aspect to Karma

There is an equivalent to Karma in Islam; the concept is quite the same in Jewish and Chritian religion: Good and evil deeds are visible to the One God Allah. It is said that all our deeds are written in the «preserved tablets», also known as «the Book of Life».

### No Concept of Nibbana

The concept of Islam is not to achieve nibbana but to live rightously in this world. The aim to get in accordance with the Will of Allah is somehow similar to Brahman practices however the way is not seeked through an absense of any desire but rather an active desire to do the Will of God.

### Forgiving and Faith

Allah promises to forgive evil deeds to those who repent and do good deeds but he will not forgive the hipocrites - those who are not constant in faith and only try to seem correct.

The Holy Quran 24:37-38

> By men who neither trading nor commerce distracts them from God’s
> remembrance, and from performing the prayers, and from giving alms.
> They fear a Day when hearts and sights are overturned. God will reward
> them according to the best of what they did, and He will increase them
> from His bounty. God provides for whomever He wills without reckoning.

The Holy Quran 5:9

> God has promised those who believe and work righteousness: they will
> have forgiveness and a great reward.

This promise is not given to those who do not believe in Allah the one God. As to those who do not know the Message of God, this verse may apply:

The Holy Quran 23:117

> Whoever invokes another god besides God —he has no proof thereof— his
> reckoning rests with his Lord. The disbelievers will not succeed.

And to those who know:

The Holy Quran 5:10

> As for those who disbelieve and reject Our revelations—these are the inmates of Hell.

### The Judgement on the Last Day

The reward is not to be expected during life.

Islam does not believe in reincarnation (but other than worshipping deities it is not counted among the sins to believe in reincarnation, just alien to the teaching of the Quran). The Karma is collected in one life. The Judgement will take place on the Last Day:

The Holy Quran, Surah 12:47:

> We will set up the scales of justice for the Day of Resurrection, so
> that no soul will suffer the least injustice. And even if it be the
> weight of a mustard-seed, We will bring it up. Sufficient are We as
> Reckoners.